# How to put value of span tag in php variable

Tags: php

I have `<span id="count"></span>`
which is basically changing its value on click.

Part of my javascript code is

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#stars').on('starrr:change', function(e, value){
    $('#count').html(value);
  });      

});
```

**How to store the value of id count in a variable in php.**

I tried:

```
<?php $var = ?><span id="count"></span><?php ; ?>
```

But I am getting error.

I cant store it in hidden field because its value changing on click.

**Is there a way such that When I click a "Post" button whatever the value of #count it get stored it in php variable so I can insert into database.**

Thanks.

Comment: You must send your value to server with ajax

Comment: Can you show me how

Comment: You can't change the value of a php variable by javascript after the page loads.

Comment: Is there a way such that When I click a button whatever the value of  #count it get stored it in php variable so I can insert into database.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side and PHP is server side

You must send your value to server with ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stars').on('starrr:change', function(e, value) {
        $('#count').html(value);
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveVariable.php",
            data: {value:value}
        }).done(function() {

        });
    });

});
```

saveVariable.php

```
$var=$_REQUEST["value"];
```

Comment: how to get value from saveVariable.php page so I can check it

Comment: instated `saveVariable.php` you can use your php file and then use `$var` in your page

Comment: ok not working.  I changed `url: "review.php"` and `$var=$_REQUEST["value"];` when I want to move the value I put `<a href="feedback?id=<?php echo $var; ?>" >` I get no value

Answer (score -1):

Try like this...

```
$value = "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#count').html();</script>"; ?>
echo $value;
```